# Location based homekit automation is not triggering

Tags: ios, icloud, appletv, homekit

I use and AppleTV4K on ios 11.1 and an iPhone7 with ios 11.1.

I have an automation set up that automatically turns on some hue lights when I come home. For some reason, this never seems to be triggered though. The location I set for my home is definitely correct, and I'm logged into icloud on both devices. Triggering the automation manually works just fine.

Is there anything I'm missing? Why is the automation never triggered?

Comment: I have the same issue, I've updated and rebooted my Apple TV with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I was fighting this exact same problem for a while, myself - everything except location automation was functioning.  My troubles were in my iCloud settings - my location was determined based on a device which was no longer in service, instead of my iPhone.  So, HomeKit interpreted things as if I was always away from home.  After updating the location settings to track on my iPhone, the automations fired back up properly again.

Hopefully this helps a few others out, ha.